# getting latitude longitude 0.0 from googleMap.getCameraPosition().target

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I was trying to get latitude and longitude of center of the map. I am using Fragment to show map that is,

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapID);
if (fm != null) {
    googleMap = fm.getMap();
}
LatLng loc = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

I am printing this loc and i am getting value as 0.0, 0.0. I am not getting where i am going wrong.

I tried to use `VisibleRegion` also to get latitude and longitude of center of map but even that did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are requesting the camera position when the map was not yet loaded, therefore the camera is pointing to 0.0, 0.0. Instead use this:

```
googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        Log.e("TAG", googleMap.getCameraPosition().target.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya correct. That worked thanks. And one more thing is there any listener so as user drags map then i get lat long from center of the map.

Comment: @NaveenKumar you can try using `setOnCameraChangeListener` and re-fetch the lat-lng there.

Answer (score 1):

Before you get these values, You must declare this Listener

- setOnCameraMoveListener : while camera is moving.
- setOnCameraIdleListener : after ceme

or any Listener like this.

```
GoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                double CameraLat = map.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
                double CameraLong = map.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;

            }
        });
```