# How to get the location of centered place pin on Map like uber android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps-v2

Someone please explain me how to get the location of centered place pin on Google Map Like in this Uber App. User can move the map but pin is always centered align and We can get the location as we keep moving the map.

[image]

Comment: I believe you'll need to make the `getCameraPosition()` call on your map instance to get this to work. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485941/getting-latitude-longitude-0-0-from-googlemap-getcameraposition-target) answers your exact concern, including how to handle location change on the map (`setOnCameraChangeListener`).

Comment: i will try it and will update you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language your using so here's a javascript solution. try creating latlng variable and using that variable to both place the marker and define center. You could do Something like this

```js
var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng ("your coords here");
var mapOptions = {
 zoom :5,
 center: markerLatlng,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: markerLatlng,
 map: map,
 animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
 title: "your title here",
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DrewtiiDeath, I need help in android as it is mentioned in title also. Anyway  thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CurrentCenterPositionMap](https://github.com/leandroBorgesFerreira/CurrentCenterPositionMap)

First import the lib:

```
compile 'br.com.simplepass:mapfragmentwrapper:0.8.0'
```

Then, all you have to do is to put the MapFragmentWrapper xml tag as a container of your map fragment. Like this:

```
<br.com.simplepass.mapfragmentwrapper.MapFragmentWrapper
    android:id="@+id/map_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</br.com.simplepass.mapfragmentwrapper.MapFragmentWrapper>
```

See the result:

[image]